# How do you define a decimal number in a PEG grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar, d, peg

I have the following grammar

```
Arithmetic:
    Term     < Factor (Add / Sub)*
    Add      < "+" Factor
    Sub      < "-" Factor
    Factor   < Primary (Mul / Div)*
    Mul      < "*" Primary
    Div      < "/" Primary
    Primary  < Parens / Neg / Pos / Number / Variable
    Parens   < "(" Term ")"
    Neg      < "-" Primary
    Pos      < "+" Primary

    Dot      < "."
    Decimal  < ~(digit+ Dot? digit*)
    Integer  < digits
    Number   < Integer / Decimal

    Function < identifier (space+ Primary)+
    Variable <- identifier
```

Most everything works, except when I try to parse a decimal (such as `0.5`) it does not work. What is the proper syntax to define a Decimal parser in PEG?

I am using the Pegged library in d-lang. See [here](https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/Pegged) for the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PEG alternatives are ordered, you need to write:

```
Number   < Decimal / Integer
```

As written, `Integer / Decimal` will always match the `Integer` at the beginning of a number, so `Decimal` will never be tried.

Answer (score 0):

This line is a little odd:

```
Decimal  < ~(digit+ Dot? digit*)
```

Notice that `+` is greedy (all modifiers are) so if `Dot` is not matched, the rest must be empty. A cleaner way to do it is one of these, depending on how you like abbreviated decimals:

```
Decimal <~ digit* (Dot digit*)? # matches `.`, `1.`, and `.5`, too.
Decimal <~ digit+ (Dot digit*)? / Dot digit+ # matches `1.` and `.5`
Decimal <~ digit* (Dot digit+)? / Dot digit+ # matches `.5`
Decimal <~ digit+ (Dot digit+)? # matches no abbreviated decimals
```